# how to setup raspberry pi A+?

Tags: wireless-adapter, pi-a+

I bought a raspberry pi a+, and wanna know how to install/set it up for the first time. I don't have a keyboard, and have a wireless adapter but don't know how to connect it "wirelessly" to my laptop. Please help!!

Comment: Hello and welcome. Have you tried any of the first steps listed on the [official page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/quick-start-guide/)?

Comment: @Ghanima you are too quick for me. I was about to post that link when I saw your answer :)

Comment: i need a specific setup tutorial for the a+ model without needing a keyboard and using a wifi adapter to connect it with my laptop

Comment: @ghanima I'm in a good mood; want to take on this answer or should I? :)

Comment: @JayEye, be my guest, I am not up to it right now. (But be aware that this question might still be called to be closed as *too broad*.)

Answer (score 1):

### The Easy Way

This way works with NOOBS or Raspbian

1. Buy a $10 USB Keyboard (it's a great investment!) and plug it into your Pi
2. Connect the Pi to a screen (computer monitor or television)
3. Boot the Pi and set it up

### The Hard Way

This way only works with Raspbian

1. Download the Linux Mint 17 Live DVD ISO for your laptop
   (Windows and OS X can't read the Pi's Raspbian Linux ext4 filesystem)
2. Burn the ISO to a blank DVD
3. Boot your laptop off of the DVD
4. Plug your SD card into your laptop
5. Mount the SD card and add the following to the bottom of the "/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf" file on the SD card:

   ```
   network={
       ssid="YourWifiName"
       psk="YourWifiPassword"
   }
   ```
6. Unmount the SD card and plug it back into your Pi
7. Boot the Pi
8. Pray
9. From Linux Mint on your laptop, open a terminal and run the following to connect to your Pi and set it up:

   ```
   ssh pi@raspberrypi.local
   ```

or something like that...

I seriously recommend The Easy Way.

After doing it The Easy Way, you can easily connect your Pi to the WiFi by following [this guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md).

(Note: Since you have a Raspberry Pi A+, you do not have an Ethernet port on your Pi.  Unfortunately, this means that you can't use an Ethernet cable).
(Unless of course you buy a $10 USB to Ethernet adapter (a great investment!)).

Answer (score 0):

- Use an Ethernet cable to connect your Pi to your switch/router/cablebox/etc . (Yes, there are ways of setting up your wireless by mounting the sd card on another machine, but if you could follow them, you would have already found them by searching for them, and you wouldn't need this tutorial!)
- `ssh pi@raspberry.local`
- the password is "raspberry"
- Follow instructions in the link posted by @ghanima

Comment: Heh. Close - 'rasbperry'?

Comment: I did it to see if anyone was paying attention :)

Comment: -1 for the first bullet point. Even without encryption it won't auto connect to a network, and turning off network encryption is a horrible practice.

Comment: Well, not permanently! But still, you'd still have to enter the SSID manually, so yeah, I wasn't thinking obviously :)

Comment: Edited the original answer.